# Django: An Error of Getting Templates

Tags: python, django, templates

I am a beginner of Django. Now, I have a problem of getting templates. The context of my webpage contains just messy code...

Here is photo/views.py:

```
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.http import HttpResponse
from final.photo.models import Image, Audio

def List(request):
    posts = Image.objects.all()
    t = loader.get_template("list.html")
    return HttpResponse(t, { 'posts': posts })
```

Here is photo/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from final.photo.views import List

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', List),
)
```

Here is list.html: (some of the code cannot be seen on the webpage)

```
<pre>
```

```
<title>So Easy! - Scene List</title>
```

```
<h1>So Easy! Learn Chinese</h1>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

I hope someone can help me solve it! Thanks!

Comment: When you post a question it is extremely helpfull if you post the error and the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your view to the following:

```
def List(request):
    posts = Image.objects.all()

    context = RequestContext(request, {
         'posts': posts,
    })

    return render_to_response('list.html', context)
```

Also, check that your settings.py has the following:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

Finally, you'll also need to change your list.html template to make use of posts variable you're passing by using {{ posts.some_image_attribute }} in your template.

Comment: With your help, I can see my webpage now. However, I cannot put my pictures on the webpage since I did not quite understand your last comments. Here is my list.html: `{% extends "base.html" %}



{% block title %}Scene List{% endblock %}



{% block content %}



<h2>Scenes</h2>

{% for post in posts %}

<img src="{{ media_url }}{{ posts.image.name }}" />

{% endfor %}



{% endblock %}` Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your template code looks good. It seems like the issue could be due to  incorrect usage of {% block content %} in your base template though. An easy way to verify would be to add <p>text1</p> outside your for loop and check if it shows up when the view gets rendered. If it does, that means that {% block content %} works correctly and then the issue is like due to empty posts value - you can also try adding <p>text2</p> inside the for loop (or output len(posts) value) to verify if that is the case.

Comment: I tried adding <p>some text</p> to inside and outside of for loop. Both of them worked... I changed my for loop and it is like this now: `{% for item in posts %}

<img src="{{ media_url }}{{ item.image.name }}" />


{% endfor %}` And there is a small colourful square representing pictures on my webpage... If I type "127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/bedroom.jpg", I can see my picture. I am going to be crazy...

Comment: So, what do you see in HTML when template is rendered then? What's the value of the <img src=""> tag?

Comment: You can copy "http://i.stack.imgur.com/nhz3p.png" to your browser and can understand what the small colourful square means.

Comment: If I open list.html in my browser directly, it is like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WVje5.png

Comment: You shouldn't be opening template file (list.html) in browser directly. Instead, you should be triggering django view processing by visiting  http://127.0.0.1:8000/ (or whatever correct url in your case might be).

Answer (score 0):

First of all: which version of django are you using? Django 1.3 added View Classes, which make things a lot easier.

Considering you're still on Django 1.2:

1. You must set the template folder at settings.py:

   TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( 
       # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
       # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
       # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
      "/absolute/path/to/your/template/folder",
   )
2. Also you need to add a code snippet inside list.html:

   {% block content %}

   {% for item in posts %}
       
   {% endfor %}
   {% endblock %}
3. It's advised to create a base.html for your templates. After you do this, add {% extends "base.html" %} as the first line of your list.html
4. The return line of your view function should be:
   return render_to_response('list.html', { 'posts' : posts })

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am using Django 1.3 right now. I set the template dir and it worked.